# template.render() python subfunction in Django 1.11 not available

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

So, I have PyCharm 2017.2.3, and Python 3.6, and Django 1.11. while practicing on the test project, I tried to render to my `index.html` in `view.py` under my app. Below is the piece of code that I am talking about:

```
def index(request):
    db_Conn = Album.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('/music/index.html')
    context = {
        'db_Conn': db_Conn,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.re)
```

Inside `return HttpResponse`, I can get until template, but when I use a period after template to use the `render()` sub-function, I do not get any suggestion from PyCharm for `render()` instead, I could see two other functions which not relevant to my post.

Can sombody help me on this. My learning is halted due to this.

Comment: Just a suggestion, follow [this tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/) and [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/)

Comment: You shouldn't rely on your editor's autocomplete. Python is a dynamic language and static analysis frequently doesn't work. Follow the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I assume **music** is app name, so your template file should be in, `music/templates/index.html`

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
from django.utils import timezone
def index(request):    
         return render(request, 'index.html', {'start_date':timezone.now()})
```

If not understood refer to this [repo](https://github.com/RobertRajcool/templatetag)

Comment: The training video that I am referring says that we need not give the "template" name, as Django is built to understand that by default. Not sure, if that is true